# How to control volume with custom Button (not Android devices buttons)

Tags: java, android, volume

Hello i cant find an answer to my question. I create application to control an Android TV, and also i create a `Button`s for control a volume UP, DOWN, but how to do this?

Its not problem for me to send a byte to TV, but i dont know how to control the volume, specific with Up and Down.

Can u help me guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
//Create an AudioManager 
    AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
//Increase the volume
    audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
//Decrease the volume
    audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```